# Looking to Calculate Lead Times given Backlog and allocation per week

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, measure

I have two tables, one is a backlog table, and one is an allocation(production) per week table. Both have pictures below. I am looking for a power bi measure that will calculate the backlog in weeks. The answer should be about 7 weeks. (estimate is fine).

The assumption is that this is the beginning of the production week, and we are not getting any new orders.

[image] [image]

Everything i have tried failed. I have tried sumx, calculate, countrows. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: what is the calculation to determine backlog in weeks?  Cumulative sum of Allocation until you reach Backlog?

Comment: yes. So here our lead time would be 7 weeks (500+200+0+100+50+0+300)

Comment: so you want  dax formula for summing the current+next 6weeks, as of each week?

Comment: Yes. but the formula will not always be 6 weeks. It will be dynamic. I am looking for a formula that will sum up all the previous weeks but stop before the sum > "current week backlog"